# multiline values being displayed in single line within div tag in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have multiline text contents which i want to display within div tag. For this i am using javascript to pass the contents to div tag as shown below

```js
function MyFunction(){
    document.getElementById("get").innerHTML = document.getElementById("pass").value;
}
```

```css
#get{
    height : 50px;
    width : 200px;
    border:1px solid;
    overflow  : auto;
    border-color:rgb(204, 204, 204);
}
```

```html
<div id="get" style="border:1px solid" contenteditable="true">

</div>

<br>
<button onclick="MyFunction()">Fetch</button><br>
<br>
<textarea id="pass">
    Hello 
    How are You
</textarea>
```

But contents in textarea is multiline text. but it displays as a single line in html div tag as shown in above snippet i,e Hello is in one line and How are you is in a different line, but in div tag its both are displaying in same line.

Comment: Google "textarea preserve line breaks", tons of results.

Comment: Why do javascript gold badges answer obvious duplicates? Or is that how they got the gold badge in the first place?

Answer (score 5):

A simple solution is using the following CSS:

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space), using `pre-wrap`...

> ...Sequences of whitespace are preserved. Lines are broken at newline characters, at `<br>`, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

You can also use `white-space: pre;`.

Here is your code with that change:

```js
function MyFunction(){
document.getElementById("get").innerHTML = document.getElementById("pass").value;
}
```

```css
#get{
height : 50px;
width : 200px;
border:1px solid;
overflow  : auto;
border-color:rgb(204, 204, 204);
white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="get" style="border:1px solid" contenteditable="true">

</div>

<br>
<button onclick="MyFunction()">Fetch</button><br>
<br>
<textarea id="pass">
Hello 
How are You
</textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I will try this one as well!

Answer (score 1):

Changed your js function.

```js
function MyFunction(){
    var data = document.getElementById("pass").value.replace('\n', '<br>');
    document.getElementById("get").innerHTML = data;
}
```

```css
#get{
height : 50px;
width : 200px;
border:1px solid;
overflow  : auto;
border-color:rgb(204, 204, 204);
}
```

```html
<div id="get" style="border:1px solid" contenteditable="true">

</div>

<br>
<button onclick="MyFunction()">Fetch</button><br>
<br>
<textarea id="pass">
Hello 
How are You
</textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks! Solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
 <pre></pre>
```

```js
function MyFunction(){
document.getElementById("get").innerHTML = document.getElementById("pass").value;
}
```

```css
#get{
height : 50px;
width : 200px;
border:1px solid;
overflow  : auto;
border-color:rgb(204, 204, 204);
}
```

```html
<pre id="get" style="border:1px solid" contenteditable="true">

</pre>

<br>
<button onclick="MyFunction()">Fetch</button><br>
<br>
<textarea id="pass">
Hello 
How are You
</textarea>
```